# Nested namespaced keys in HugSQL Query

Tags: clojure, hugsql

I have a nested map with namespaced keys like this:

```
{
  :model.person/primary {:model.person/name "John Smith"}
}
```

Instead of simpliying this into a flat map I'd like to pass it straight through to a HugSQL function. The docs say HugSQL supports a deep parameter get and namespaced keys but I'm not sure how to combine them.

```
(hugsql/def-sqlvec-fns-from-string
  "-- :name get_person :? :1
   -- :doc Get a person
   SELECT * FROM person WHERE name = :value:model.person/primary:model.person/name")
```

Now if I execute the function it generates with my original map I get this:

```
(get_person-sqlvec {:model.person/primary {:model.person/name "John Smith"}})

Execution error (ExceptionInfo) at hugsql.core/validate-parameters! (core.clj:83).
Parameter Mismatch: :model.person/name parameter data not found.
```

I would imagine the variable naming convention in the SQL is the source of the problem:

```
:value:model.person/primary:model.person/name
```

But I'm not sure what the correct value should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the deep parameter get uses `.` between keys, not `:`, so that is part of your problem.

However, right now HugSQL only supports one level of qualified keywords -- because there is an inherent ambiguity between `.` for separating deep parameter get keys and the `.` that can be part of (qualified) keywords.

You could have `where name = :value:model.person/primary.name` and then a hash map like `{:model.person/primary {:name "John Smith"}}`

Or you could have `where name = :value:model.person/name` and pass `{:model.person/name "John Smith"}`

HugSQL will need a different syntax to support nested qualified keys (to resolve the `.` ambiguity). I mentioned Selmer's approach to Curtis Summers, HugSQL's maintainer: using `..` to indicate the dot that is part of a keyword, so you could have:

`where name = :value:model..person/primary.model..person/name`

(that's how Selmer indicates nested qualified keys) but there are backward compatibility issues to consider as well as whether that's a good syntax in the first place (I'm a heavy user of Selmer and I don't like that, but I understand why they did it).

Comment: Sean, thanks for your answer and your work on next.jdbc. Yeah I tried with the dot separator also and suspected it was not possible with two levels of namespaced keys.

I'm using the latest version of Clojure Spec (alpha2) in which I believe is idiomatic to have a fully namespaced schema. My functions typically take a map which is some subset of the schema (validated against a spec created via s/select).

I was hoping I could pass this map directly to HugSQL to keep the function clean as massaging the data just to pass to HugSQL seems to make the code a bit harder to read.

Comment: Perhaps another solution is to create a standard function to translate all fully qualified keys into simple keys and I use this across my whole app every time I call a HugSQL function. For example, the function could translate my original fully namespaced map into { :person_primary { :person_name "John Smith" }} and then in my SQL I simply have :value.person_primary.person_name.